# Select statements in Hibernate very slow when using Azure Postgresql server

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, azure

I am currently working on migrating our database in Azure from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

For this, we created a new Azure Database for PostgreSQL and connected to it via JPA/Spring. However there seems to be an issue with the Server Performance during selects, when the executed method is not marked as Transactional (with the `@Transactional` annotation in Spring).

When executing 100 consecutive select statements, the server takes 70 seconds to execute them all. When marked with `@Transactional`, this gets reduced to ~4 seconds. After a bit of investigation this seems to be a problem with Azure Database for PostgreSQL, since this neither occurred with a local Postgresql database nor with the Azure MS SQL Server.

Has anyone else experienced these issues when using Azure PostgreSQL and are there any configuration settings that could be solving this issue?

Marking all the methods to use Transaction Management would not be a proper solution since there is no reason to use Transaction Management on some select statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is always a db transaction even if you don't explicitly mark it as such. That being said when using `@Transactional` you are re-using a single connection to execute all 100 queries. If you don't you get a new connection for each query (depending on whether you are using a pool or not) and this is a very time consuming operation.

Comment: This would not explain why it is exceptionally slower when using SQL Server. There would need to be some sort of different behaviour here like keeping connections open or something.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't occur locally (no network overhead) but remote is that proof. Different DB different handshake and way of obtaining connections.